# How to check with whole raw object (without using any property) if that object contains in array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to check the entire raw object with array of objects. I dont want to compare by using any property name.

```
 const items = [{ a: 1 },{ a: 2 },{ a: 3 }];
  const item1 = { a: 2 };
```

What to do if i want to check if `item1` exist in `items` array without using any property but with  
 whole object. 
`indexOf` `filter` `some` and even `lopping` does not work on this condition. 
Need help on this. How to check? 
by the way, my condition is different. I have a long object and its uniquness depends upon lots of properties, that why I do not want to compare using properties.

I have something like this.

```
function bigArraySol() {
  const bigArray = [
    {
      product_id: "1",
      product_name: "Womens Achara",
      total_price: "8000",
      unique_product_id: "1",
      seller_id: "sell1",
      image: "https://i.imgur.com/6CsDtqD.jpg",
      quantity: 3,
      product_types: [
        {
          product_type_id: "1",
          product_type_name: "Achara Cloth",
          attributes: [
            {
              attribute_name: "Achara Length",
              attribute_value: "4"
            },
            {
              attribute_name: "Achara Cloth",
              attribute_value: "Terry Cotton"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          product_type_id: "2",
          product_type_name: "Khadki ",
          attributes: [
            {
              attribute_name: "Khadki Cloth",
              attribute_value: "Ready Made"
            },
            {
              attribute_name: "khadki Color",
              attribute_value: "mix"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          product_type_id: "3",
          product_type_name: "Blouse",
          attributes: [
            {
              attribute_name: "Blouse Size",
              attribute_value: "20"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      product_id: "1",
      product_name: "Womens Achara",
      total_price: "8000",
      unique_product_id: "1",
      seller_id: "sell1",
      image: "https://i.imgur.com/6CsDtqD.jpg",
      quantity: 3,
      product_types: [
        {
          product_type_id: "1",
          product_type_name: "Achara Cloth",
          attributes: [
            {
              attribute_name: "Achara Length",
              attribute_value: "4"
            },
            {
              attribute_name: "Achara Cloth",
              attribute_value: "Terry Cotton"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          product_type_id: "2",
          product_type_name: "Khadki ",
          attributes: [
            {
              attribute_name: "Khadki Cloth",
              attribute_value: "Ready Made"
            },
            {
              attribute_name: "khadki Color",
              attribute_value: "mix"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          product_type_id: "3",
          product_type_name: "Blouse",
          attributes: [
            {
              attribute_name: "Blouse Size",
              attribute_value: "25"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      product_id: "1",
      product_name: "Womens Achara",
      total_price: "8000",
      unique_product_id: "1",
      seller_id: "sell1",
      image: "https://i.imgur.com/6CsDtqD.jpg",
      quantity: 3,
      product_types: [
        {
          product_type_id: "1",
          product_type_name: "Achara Cloth",
          attributes: [
            {
              attribute_name: "Achara Length",
              attribute_value: "4"
            },
            {
              attribute_name: "Achara Cloth",
              attribute_value: "Terry Cotton"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          product_type_id: "2",
          product_type_name: "Khadki ",
          attributes: [
            {
              attribute_name: "Khadki Cloth",
              attribute_value: "Ready Made"
            },
            {
              attribute_name: "khadki Color",
              attribute_value: "mix"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          product_type_id: "3",
          product_type_name: "Blouse",
          attributes: [
            {
              attribute_name: "Blouse Size",
              attribute_value: "25"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const compairingObj = {
    product_id: "1",
    product_name: "Womens Achara",
    total_price: "8000",
    unique_product_id: "1",
    seller_id: "sell1",
    image: "https://i.imgur.com/6CsDtqD.jpg",
    quantity: 3,
    product_types: [
      {
        product_type_id: "1",
        product_type_name: "Achara Cloth",
        attributes: [
          {
            attribute_name: "Achara Length",
            attribute_value: "4"
          },
          {
            attribute_name: "Achara Cloth",
            attribute_value: "Terry Cotton"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        product_type_id: "2",
        product_type_name: "Khadki ",
        attributes: [
          {
            attribute_name: "Khadki Cloth",
            attribute_value: "Ready Made"
          },
          {
            attribute_name: "khadki Color",
            attribute_value: "mix"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        product_type_id: "3",
        product_type_name: "Blouse",
        attributes: [
          {
            attribute_name: "Blouse Size",
            attribute_value: "20"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

see in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-q8yu6?file=/index.js:0-4933

Comment: `item1` does not exist in `items`, and without comparing against properties you cannot tell if a similar object does exist in it.

Comment: but {a:2} is similar with the first index value of an array.
isn't it?

Comment: You have to use properties, because objects have different links, so you cannot find it by a link

Comment: Similar yes, but they're not the same object. So you need to check the property names/values, which you said you do not want.

Comment: btw, but why don't you want to use properties?

Comment: please see my updated question @Georgy

Comment: What about stringifying them both and comparing them that way? `JSON.stringify({a:2}) === JSON.stringify({a:2})`

Comment: what result do you expect for the longer data sets?

Comment: i am expecting that `compairingObj` exists in `bigArray` @NinaScholz

Comment: I wonder why you cannot use unique IDs to check if your product exists in some array of products. Unless I am missing something from your requirement?

Comment: Its like, there is a product and product has different attributes like size, length, color, height size, waist size, and many more. And due to that price also vary. That's why I do not want to use property to compare. And same unique product can be ordered with different size and attributes. That's why I do not want to use properties.
however you answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply JSON stringify them and compare.

```js
const items = [{ a: 1 },{ a: 2 },{ a: 3 }];
const item1 = { a: 2 };

items.map((item, index) => {
  if (JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(item1)) {
    console.log('item1 exists in index ' + index);
  }
})
```

Comment: I just thought of this too 

Comment: yes and no - yes because stringify works for the above example, but no because use `.some()` for a boolean result, or `.find()` to find the matching object, not a `.map()`, you're not transforming the array, so map isnt the correct function in this case

Comment: There is no guarantee that field order will match - is there?

Comment: no but given the example, it works.  A better solution would be to compare the properties themselves, but thats another discussion

Comment: Helped this in this condition

Answer (score 0):

This code uses loops, and looks at properties, to implement an "object-in-array indexOf". It is very simple, and will match any object in the `haystack` that has the same values for each of the properties of the `needle` object. It should be easy to modify to check that the match does not have properties *not* found in the needle - but I am unsure of your needs.

```js
const indexOf = (needle, haystack) => {
  let index = -1;
  haystack.every((o,i) => {
    let found = true;
    for (let [k,v] of Object.entries(needle)) {
      if (o[k] !== v) { found = false; break; } 
    }
    if (found) index=i;
    return !found; // false exits
  });
  return index;
}

const haystack = [{ a: 1 },{ a: 2 },{ a: 3 }];
const needle = { a: 2 };

console.log(indexOf(needle, haystack)); // returns 1
```